# Image as a Radio button

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I want to use radio button in my form. I am using AngularJS to create my form. But i want image instead of radio button. I am able to hide the radio button by adding css

```
position: absolute;
left: -9999px;
```

But the problem with this is it's disabling the checked event. Is there any way to make image clickable.

**Here is my code:**

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {         

  $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {
    // check to make sure the form is completely valid
    if (isValid) {
      alert('our form is amazing');
      console.log(myform);
    }
  };
  $scope.sliderValue = null;
  $scope.name = '';    
  $scope.data = {
    singleSelect: null,
    multipleSelect: [],
    option1: 'option-1',
  };
  $scope.forceUnknownOption = function() {
    $scope.data.singleSelect = 'nonsense';
  };

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <form name='myform' id="myform" ng-init="step = 1" ng-submit="submitForm(myform.$valid)">

      <div ng-show="step==1">
        <h3>Which step</h3>
        <div ng-form='step1form'>
          <input type="radio" name="step" ng-model="data.step" value="11" ng-disabled="!step1form.$valid" ng-click="step = 2">
          <img src="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico" style="width:50px" alt="Save icon"/>
          <p class="Text">
            Step 2
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div ng-show="step==2">
        <div ng-form='step2form'>
          <div ng-disabled="!step2form.$valid"><span>Finish</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

    <script>document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");</script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: wrap it in label element and just add classes with image sprites.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used awesome icons. You can do it like this:

```html
<label class="hideRadio">
  <input class="" type="radio" value="" name="">
  <i class="fa fa-check-circle "></i>
</label>
```

and use this css:

```css
.hideRadio input {
  visibility: hidden; /* Makes input not-clickable */
  position: absolute; /* Remove input from document flow */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to associate a label with your radio input and style that with your image. You can see in this demo that, when you style the label it acts in place of the input

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').click(function() {
    alert($('input').val());
  });
});
```

```css
label.radioLabel {
  background: pink;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
}
input[type=radio] {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: -9999px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>No label</h1>
<input type="radio" name="step">
<h1>Label Wrapped Around</h1>
<label class="radioLabel">
  <input type="radio" name="step">
</label>
<h1>Label With "For"</h1>
<input type="radio" id="step" name="step">
<label class="radioLabel" for="step"></label>
```

Obviously use your own styles on the label, but I recommend keeping `cursor:pointer;` so the interaction is apparent to your users.

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
    <label>
<input type="radio" name="step" ng-model="data.step" value="11" ng-disabled="!step1form.$valid" ng-click="step = 2">
<img src="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico" style="width:50px" alt="Save icon"/>
 </label>
```

css:

```
label > input{ /* HIDE RADIO */
  display:none;
}
label > input + img{ /* IMAGE STYLES */
  cursor:pointer;
  border:2px solid transparent;
}
label > input:checked + img{ /* (CHECKED) IMAGE STYLES */
  border:2px solid #f00;
}
```

https://jsbin.com/modotayufe/edit?html,css,js,output

Answer (score 1):

The trick is to wrap the input with label so when you click on it it's like you clicked on the radio button. In the label, put a `span` tag so you can set his background to your image.

In the below snippet you can see this in action. (I commented the `ng-change` attribute so you can see the effect)

```js
var app = angular.module("MyApp", []);

app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope, $timeout) {         

  $scope.submitForm = function(isValid) {
    // check to make sure the form is completely valid
    if (isValid) {
      alert('our form is amazing');
      console.log(myform);
    }
  };
  $scope.sliderValue = null;
  $scope.name = '';    
  $scope.data = {
    singleSelect: null,
    multipleSelect: [],
    option1: 'option-1',
  };
  $scope.forceUnknownOption = function() {
    $scope.data.singleSelect = 'nonsense';
  };

});
```

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  display:none;  
}

input[type="radio"] + span {
  content:"";
  background:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/hlkG5.png);
  width:30px;
  height:30px;
  display:inline-block;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + span {
  background-image:url(https://i.stack.imgur.com/TwN4q.png);  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <form name='myform' id="myform" ng-init="step = 1" ng-submit="submitForm(myform.$valid)">

      <div ng-show="step==1">
        <h3>Which step</h3>
        <div ng-form='step1form'>
          <label>
            <input type="radio" name="step" ng-model="data.step" value="11" ng-disabled="!step1form.$valid"><!--ng-click="step = 2"-->
            <span></span>
          </label>
          <img src="http://sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/favicon.ico" style="width:50px" alt="Save icon"/>
          <p class="Text">
            Step 2
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>

      <div ng-show="step==2">
        <div ng-form='step2form'>
          <div ng-disabled="!step2form.$valid"><span>Finish</span></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </form>

    <script>document.write("<base href=\"" + document.location + "\" />");</script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.6/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You are welcome. I don't understand actually how the accepted answer helps you. It's not behave like radio button. Isn't?

Comment: actually i wanted to hide the radio button symbol n still make it clickable on clicking image.

Comment: So you definitely don't need a radio button, you need a simple button.

Comment: yeah, but i wanted to capture the form data where each question has more than one option. so i used radio button